# Running two instructions simultaneusly

Tags: python, simultaneous

I need to run at the same time this two instruction within a python script.

- GPIO.output(17,True)
- os.system('gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download')

it is important to start them simultaneously.

How can I do that?

Comment: How would it be different to what you want if instead you just ran the two in the order you have them now?

Comment: Because the os.system command take an exposure with a camera and the GPIO.ouput start a chronometer that the camera looks. So I want to measure the delay time between the os command and the effective camera shot.

Comment: Please update your question with the actual parameters you will be using with these two calls.

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually possible, in the sense that even if you computer has multiple cores, I'm not sure there is a way to ensure two instructions are actually executed literally at the same time by two different cores. You'll probably always end up with a few clock ticks of error (which is usually less than 1e-9 seconds), as if you were executing them in order.

Comment: There is no way to know how long it will take for the `gphoto2` app to start, therefore you can never know when the GPIO pin should be activated. You might as well run the two commands in sequence and try some sort of calibration.

Answer (score 0):

As you know - Python is single - threaded. But you can get around this with several ways:

- Run multiple Python threads. For example: split your script for to scripts and run them with to different python process simultaneously, like `python script1.py` in one terminal window and `python script2.py` in second terminal window.
- Use [multi-thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module which allows run Python functions in different threads. You can easily find a lot of quick tutorials or just read official docs above.
- Also Python allows use [multi-process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) too. The idea is similar like splitting your script on different scripts.

Comment: What’s the best way to make sure they start at the same time? This is crucial for the purpose.

Comment: @LucaRosignoli if you have single core CPU you will not run two programmes in same time. It's impossible because CPU with single core can execute only one instruction for the time. If you have multi core CPU you can run your progremme simultaneusly. But you could not be shure that you run your programme in the same time because of OS. I guess you could not find a good solution for your problem. Not on python at least.